# nginx same location but with different directives

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Trying to see if this is possible.

We have an app and a wordpress install.

Is it possible to use 2 locations for the same folder but under different circumstances. Example..

http://domain.com/subfolder/ - This shows the APP
http://domain.com/subfolder/anything - This shows WP permalink

Right now, we have it so

http://domain.com/subfolder (without the /) shows the app

http://domain.com/subfolder/ (witht the /) shows WP.

This does work, but would it be possible to have it so, it will only show WP IF the URL contains text after subfolder/*

Current Nginx conf:

```
location  ^~ /knowledge {

root /opt/domain.com/public/;
try_files $uri @backend;
}

location /knowledge/ {
index index.php index.html index.htm;

root /opt;
include /etc/nginx/php-wpsc.conf;
try_files $uri $uri/ /knowledge/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it makes sense to keep the `location /knowledge/` block for WordPress, as that matches the majority of cases, with just one case that needs to be overridden.

A specific URI can be taken away from that location block by using a location block with a higher precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

One possibility would be an exact match location block:

```
location = /knowledge/ {
    rewrite ^ /knowledge last;
}
```

Or possibly, change your existing `location  ^~ /knowledge` block from a prefix location to a regular expression location, making the trailing `/` optional.

```
location ~ ^/knowledge/? { ... }
```

Note that this changes the order of evaluation of this location block, so there may be side-effects that need to be considered.